# Adding ComboBox Items to Name of File on Save

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Currently I am able to Save Active Sheet as a new Hard Coded Worksheet name by using this code:

```
Sub SaveSheet()
    Dim FName As String
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    FName = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\TestSheet" & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

As you can see the new worksheet will store as `TestSheet.slxm` at the directory now instead of hardcoding the name I have a `UserForm1` which looks like :

[image]

and has been populated as:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 With ComboBox1
   .AddItem "Region 1"
   .AddItem "Region 2"
   .AddItem "Region 3"
   .AddItem "Region 4"
   .AddItem "Region 4"
 End With
End Sub
```

Now cab you please let me know how I can get the name of selected Item(Region) and add to the : FName instead of that hard coded name (Testsheet)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the click event of the command button. Something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FName As String

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With

    If ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    FName = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\" & _
            ComboBox1.Value & _
            Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth and thanks again for reply.However I am dealing with some confusing issues here! First of all , to be honest I am not sure where to put the save sub! I mean when I open the developer there are 3 option to put the code: 1-: Inserting A Module and Run the codes there 2- Clicking on Microsoft Office object Items :Sheet1(Sheet1)  and 3: running the code from User Control Form. Let me explain ehat I need to do: We are etting some excel sheets daily or even hourly from our fields which we have to format them like removing some Rows and Reformatting Cell values

Comment: After doing all of them We need to save the currently formatted and edited field into a New Worksheet in the directry

Comment: You need to double click on the "Save As New Excel" button in design mode and then put the code there. For example what is the name of that button?

Comment: Now Can you please let me know where should I put all codes which can be save as a Macro and be usable for all recieving files?

Comment: Please see my last comment.

Comment: Thanks but please be advise that the save option is the last command which I need to use

Comment: I understand but can you answer my comment? What is the name of that button?

Comment: I mean I need to clean data before saving them and it is going to involve reformatting 120 columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43378/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-behseini)